# UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I've been looking around for this solution for a while but haven't got any. 
e.g one solution is

```
 self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Stop, target: self, action: nil), animated: true)
```

This code will add a button with "stop" image. Just like this, there are other solutions with "search, "refresh" etc. But **what if I want to add a button programmatically with the image I want?**

Answer (score 376, accepted):

**Custom button image without setting button frame:**

You can use `init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: Any?, action: Selector?)` to initializes a new item using the specified image and other properties.

```
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imagename"), style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector("action")) // action:#selector(Class.MethodName) for swift 3
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1
```

Check this [Apple Doc. reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init)

---

### **UIBarButtonItem with custom button image using button frame**

**FOR `Swift 3.0`**

```
    let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

    let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
    btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)  

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1,item2], animated: true)
```

---

**FOR `Swift 2.0` and older**

```
let btnName = UIButton()
btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)
btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

//.... Set Right/Left Bar Button item
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
rightBarButton.customView = btnName
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

> Or simply use [init(customView:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/) like
>
> ```
>  let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnName)
>  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
> ```

---

**For System UIBarButtonItem**

```
let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = camera
```

---

**For set more then 1 items use `rightBarButtonItems` or for left side `leftBarButtonItems`**

```
let btn1 = UIButton()
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "img1"), forState: .Normal)
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action1:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem()
item1.customView = btn1

let btn2 = UIButton()
btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "img2"), forState: .Normal)
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
btn2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action2:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem()
item2.customView = btn2

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [item1,item2]
```

**Using `setLeftBarButtonItem` or `setRightBarButtonItem`**

```
let btn1 = UIButton()
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "img1"), forState: .Normal)
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action1:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1), animated: true);
```

> For swift >= 2.2 action should be `#selector(Class.MethodName)` ... for e.g. `btnName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Comment: Great answer. Just want to point out that the Selector method has been updated though to `let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName))`

Comment: I found that if you want your button to also include the text you must specify the CGRect portion. There are some examples floating around SO that don't specify this.

Answer (score 53):

It's much easier with `Swift 4` or `Swift 4.2`

inside your `ViewDidLoad` method, define your button and add it to the navigation bar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoutBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(logoutUser))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = logoutBarButtonItem

}
```

then you need to define the function that you mentioned inside action parameter as below

```
@objc func logoutUser(){
     print("clicked")
}
```

You need to add the `@objc` prefix as it's still making use of the legacy stuff (Objective C).

Answer (score 17):

Just setup `UIBarButtonItem` with customView

For example:

```
  var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:yourButton)
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

or use `setFunction`:

```
  self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourButton), animated: true);
```

Comment: I am up voting your answer as your code works as well but Bhavin's code is a one shot solution so I'll accept his answer. Thanks for your contribution mate :)

Answer (score 12):

I just stumbled upon this question and here is an update for Swift 3 and iOS 10:

```
let testUIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "test.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = testUIBarButtonItem
```

It is definitely much faster than creating the UIButton with all the properties and then subsequently adding the customView to the UIBarButtonItem.

And if you want to change the color of the image from the default blue to e.g. white, you can always change the tint color:

```
test.tintColor = UIColor.white()
```

PS You should obviously change the selector etc. for your app :)

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3.0+, `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically set up as follows:

```swift
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testUIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "test.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.clickButton))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = testUIBarButtonItem
    }

   @objc func clickButton(){
            print("button click")
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

FOR Swift 5+

```
let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "searchIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onSearchButtonClicked))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = searchBarButtonItem

@objc func onSearchButtonClicked(_ sender: Any){
    print("SearchButtonClicked")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting LeftBarButton with Original Image.

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imagename").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(classname.functionname))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = menuButton
```

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 11**

Setting a custom button using constraint:

```
let buttonWidth = CGFloat(30)
let buttonHeight = CGFloat(30)

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "img name"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight).isActive = true

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and I have read  answers in another topic then I solve another similar way. I do not know which is more effective.
[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815534/adding-uibarbutton-item-in-swift)

```
//play button

@IBAction func startIt(sender: AnyObject) {
    startThrough();
};

//play button

func startThrough() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

    let pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "pauseIt");
    self.toolBarIt.items?.removeLast();
    self.toolBarIt.items?.append( pauseButton );
}

func pauseIt() {
    timer.invalidate();

    let play = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Play, target: self, action: "startThrough");
    self.toolBarIt.items?.removeLast();
    self.toolBarIt.items?.append( play );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

addition to the above you may use the following for ios14 and above

```
   if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        let closeAction = UIAction(handler: { [weak self] _ in
           //perform action here
        })
        let closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .close, primaryAction: closeAction, menu: nil)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = closeBarButtonItem
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func viewDidLoad(){
let homeBtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

        homeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Home.png"), for: [])

        homeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        homeBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        let homeButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: homeBtn)


        let backBtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

        backBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "back.png"), for: [])

        backBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        backBtn.frame = CGRect(x: -10, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backButton,homeButton], animated: true)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a crazy thing of apple. When you say self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title then it will say nil while on the GUI it shows Edit or Save. Fresher likes me will take a lot of time to debug this behavior.

There is a requirement that the Item will show Edit in the firt load then user taps on it It will change to Save title. To archive this, i did as below.

//view did load will say Edit title

```
private func loadRightBarItem() {
    let logoutBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleEditBtn))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = logoutBarButtonItem
}
```

// tap Edit item will change to Save title

```
@objc private func handleEditBtn() {
    print("clicked on Edit btn")
    let logoutBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleSaveBtn))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = logoutBarButtonItem
    blockEditTable(isBlock: false)
}
```

//tap Save item will display Edit title

```
@objc private func handleSaveBtn(){
    print("clicked on Save btn")
    let logoutBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleEditBtn))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = logoutBarButtonItem

    saveInvitation()
    blockEditTable(isBlock: true)

}
```