# how to make UIBarButtonItem class from UI Button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

[image]

I am a beginner I want to make a top bar button that has badge like the picture above, after searching on the internet, I can make the badge on the button by implementing the `SSBadgeButton` like the code below

```
import UIKit

class SSBadgeButton: UIButton {

    var badgeLabel = UILabel()

    var badge: String? {
        didSet {
            addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
        }
    }

    public var badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
        }
    }

    public var badgeTextColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
        }
    }

    public var badgeFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) {
        didSet {
            badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
        }
    }

    public var badgeEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets? {
        didSet {
            addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
    }

    func addBadgeToButon(badge: String?) {
        badgeLabel.text = badge
        badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
        badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
        badgeLabel.sizeToFit()
        badgeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        let badgeSize = badgeLabel.frame.size

        let height = max(18, Double(badgeSize.height) + 5.0)
        let width = max(height, Double(badgeSize.width) + 10.0)

        var vertical: Double?, horizontal: Double?
        if let badgeInset = self.badgeEdgeInsets {
            vertical = Double(badgeInset.top) - Double(badgeInset.bottom)
            horizontal = Double(badgeInset.left) - Double(badgeInset.right)

            let x = (Double(bounds.size.width) - 10 + horizontal!)
            let y = -(Double(badgeSize.height) / 2) - 10 + vertical!
            badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        } else {
            let x = self.frame.width - CGFloat((width / 2.0))
            let y = CGFloat(-(height / 2.0))
            badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))
        }

        badgeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = badgeLabel.frame.height/2
        badgeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        addSubview(badgeLabel)
        badgeLabel.isHidden = badge != nil ? false : true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

as we can see the `SSBadgeButton`is UIButton, and I need to convert that `SSBadgeButton` to `UIBarButtonItem`. the purpose of this is to make the `UIBarButtonItem` class to be accessible in the Interface builder as the custom class like the picture below

[image]

Comment: You need to add your custom button as customView in your UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Anyway you can add a UIButton as navigationBar button simply dragging it in the storybord, to your navigation navigation bar and changing the button class to your class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert the `UIButton` to `UIBarButtonItem`, you can always create `UIBarbuttonItem` using `UIButton` as shown below

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("ABCD", for: .normal)
    let uiBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [uiBarButtonItem]
```

Instead of UIButton you will use your `SSBadgeButton` thats all

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can create `UIBarButtonItem` with custom button

```
let button = SSBadgeButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
let barBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```