# How to add a custom uiview to uibackbuttonitem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a `UILabel` as a custom view to the `backButtonItem` of the `navigationItem` but it doesn’t show up.

I want to achieve something like the Mail iOS App as in the following picture where the back button shows the number of unread messages with a background and nice corner radius.

Refer reference image.

[image]

Comment: you can refer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically

Comment: Can you show us what have you done coding on `backButtonItem` so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically)

Comment: You don't add a custom view to the `navigationItem` on the `backButtonItem`, you just add it as a new button item. Refer to @SagarBhut 's comment to see how to create the item.