# The image for my UIBarButtonItem keeps stretching to the center?

Tags: ios, button, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a basic Settings icon in the top right of the navigation bar. I added a UIBarButtonItem to my navigation bar. Then I set the image, but it moved the image to the center instead of staying in the right? Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift/35233701

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to do with that answer @BencePattogato. It is a different issue and not updated for Swift 4 either.

Comment: I'm assuming you want that to be a settings **button**? If so, check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically

Comment: Looks like you got this resolved but in the future its better to post your code so others can diagnose it.

Comment: This was more of an Interface Builder issue than it was a code related issue @Dancreek

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I fixed this by decreasing the dimensions of the icon closer to 40x40. It was too large.