# How can I add title and image on a bar buttonitem for a toolbar of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How it is possible to add an image and text on a UIBarButtonItem on a navigation controller just like on modern apps such as Photos, ebay etc (see [Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaAO6.png))

I know this is possible in Interface Builder if you add a toolbar manually to a view but this is not possible if using navigation controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift  ,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815534/adding-uibarbutton-item-in-swift . --see this link

Comment: Your linked image is of a tab bar, not a toolbar.

Comment: @Md Rasted Pervez Thanks for the links - however the code only shows how to add an image but I would like both title and image

Comment: @rmaddy: That is probably true. Nonetheless I would achieve something like this on a toolbar.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `title` and `image` properties on [`UIBarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem?language=objc)?

Comment: @jefflovejapan. UIBarItem is an abstract superclass. Hence I cannot instantiate it directly. Was your idea to implement a concrete subclass from UIBarItem?

Comment: @iKiwi Ah, I see. Can you instantiate `UITabBarItem`s, assign values to the `title` and `image`, and add them to your toolbar? Also, just to clarify, these are being added to an instance of `UIToolbar`, right?

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea. Unfortunately I cannot use a UITabBarItem as it is not a subclass of UIView: 
let test: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Registration", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Registration"), tag: 1)
        let baritem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: test)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` you can set the left and the right bar button of the view controller with

```
// System item
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(action))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(action))
// Tittle
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
// Image
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
// Custom view
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
```

Comment: Interesting but what  I want is to have an item and image at the same time. If I set an image on the UIBarButtonItem the title will not be shown.
I was trying to use a custom view and using a vertical stack container but it will not be displayed at all for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I got so far. This, however only displays a text right to the image:

```
   //Create a UIButton with an image on the left, and text to the right
    var buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Lab")
    var button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    button.setImage(buttonImage, for: UIControlState.normal);
    button.setTitle("Caption", for: UIControlState.normal);
```